# Bulma multiselect size not working?

Tags: html, css, bulma

In [bulma's](http://bulma.io/documentation/form/select/) latest update they support multi select.

But it's not working for me? Obviously I'm doing something wrong but I've no idea what. When I copy the example on their site:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.3/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="select is-multiple">
  <select multiple size="8">
    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
    <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
    <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
    <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I only see the first item. What am I missing here? I want to see 8 items at once.

Comment: Press cntrl + click to multi-select. The reason you are only seeing one item is, because your list-box is not big enough.  /* height: 2.25em; */

Comment: Multiple select is part of version 0.4.4, and you are using 0.4.3.

Comment: @OriDrori when change that in my project I get: `Please choose a version from this list: (Use arrow keys)
❯ 0.4.3 
  0.4.2 
  0.4.1 
  0.4.0 
  0.3.2 ` so no `0.4.4` is it in beta?

Comment: @Jenssen Even on their showcase website, you can multiselect in that select-box using shift + click/cntrl + click.  In css your selectbox is being styled to be only this height /* height: 2.25em; */, so if you change the height you will be able to see more items, and select them using methods I have mentioned above.

Comment: @Jenssen - that's what is written under multi select in the link you've supplied.

Comment: Both the select and the parent div have `height: 2.25em` set (coming from form.sass) - you would need to overwrite that with `auto`, and also overwrite the ::after element, if you want to get rid of the arrow as well.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe that works.

Answer (score -5):

**Might be some changes in CDN file.**

please open this link http://bulma.io/css/bulma-docs.css (Copy all css).

Instead of cdn file please **create one custom file called bulma.css** and **copy & paste code** from the above link. and just **include custom file** that you created and **removed the cdn file**.

So it will look some thing like this.

[image]